# Customization of css attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to customize the color attribute of this element this way:

```
<h2 style="float:left;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;color:#fbfbfb;font-size:40px;position:relative;margin-top:-458px;margin-left:90px;" class="main-title">TEST</h2>
```

js code (included in the top of the html page)

```
(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('main-title').color = 'black';
})();
```

Doing this wouldn't change the color. Including it at the bottom of the page involves the same issue. Also, I've tried to include a css file which contains(`.main-title{color:black;}`) instead of that js file, but it still the same. How to fix this, please?

Any brilliant idea ?

Comment: when you want to change the `color` on document load ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be

```
document.getElementsByClassName('main-title')[0].style.color = 'black';
```

Because `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection not a single element. And `color` is a key in style property.

You have `Top-margin = -458px` so that element will never appear. So may be you are not able to view that element itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `style` property of the element

```
document.getElementsByClassName('main-title')[0].style.color = 'black';
```

You can also update all the elements with this classname with the following

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('main-title');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
    els[0].style.color = 'black'
}
```